# change ng repeat collection name on button click to change the result list

Tags: angularjs

How to change ng repeat collection on button click to change the result list.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in collectionName">........</li>
```

Can we decide the name of collection to a scope variable value on button click.
Idea is on each tab click the change function will change the scope variable value, which also change the collection name and hence the result list get changed.

Controller code:

```
app.controller("LinkController", function($scope){
    $scope.linkRef='';
    $scope.List1=[{name:'tab1'},{name:'tab2'}];
    $scope.List2=[{name:'tab3'},{name:'tab4'}];   
    $scope.load=function(){
       //based on condition will change the linkRef to List1 or List2
       this.linkRef=List1     
    }
} );
```

the collectionName in ng-repeat should replaced to List1 or List2 as per the linkref value.

Comment: Can you provide more explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6rhd1sq/1/)

This is my suggestion.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.collections = [];
$scope.collections.push(['collection 1 content', 'item1', 'item2']);
$scope.collections.push(['collection 2 content', 'item3', 'item4']);

$scope.currentCollection = $scope.collections[0];

$scope.setCollection = function(val) {
    $scope.currentCollection = $scope.collections[val];
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-click="setCollection(0)">TAB 1</li>
    <li ng-click="setCollection(1)">TAB 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in currentCollection">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It help me to get the desired result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" ng-click="collectionName=collection1"> tabl </a>
<a href="#" ng-click="collectionName=collection2"> tab2 </a>
<a href="#" ng-click="collectionName=collection3"> tab3 </a>
<a href="#" ng-click="collectionName=collection4"> tab4 </a>
```